# set_include_path() to include Zend Framework doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to include the Zend Framework in my web project.

The path to the Zend Library is saved in the following variable:

```
$zendPath =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/name/zend/library/";
```

I'm using `set_include_path()` in this way:

```
set_include_path($zendPath . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
```

Both of these lines are in a file called `user.inc.php`

In another file called `index.php` there are the following lines:

```
require_once "user.inc.php";
require_once 'Zend/Http/Client.php';
```

This doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Client' not found in /srv/www/htdocs/name/project/index.php on line 26
```

However, if I'm removing `set_include_path()` from `user.inc.php` and change the `Client.php` require statment to `require_once $zendPath.'Zend/Http/Client.php';`, it works. Obviously, it only works for `Client.php` and not for other classes of the Zend Framework that are required by `Client.php`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check include_path variable, if it's properly set after set_include_path($zendPath . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

2) Try to put set_include_path($zendPath . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()); to index.php and test it

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I created the instance of a wrong class, because I'm working with Zend Framework 1 and not Zend Framework 2. It works now when using the correct class.